# How to class the superclass of a superclass in Swift?

Tags: swift

`ArtistVC` is a subclass of `CategoryVC` which is a subclass of `BrowserVC`.

Most of `ArtistVC`'s UITableView Data Source methods wind up calling `CategoryVC`'s implementation of those methods with `return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: adjustedIndexPath)`(for example), after some other things happen of course, like modifying the `indexPath` passed to the method.

But sometimes I actually want to bypass `CategoryVC`'s implementation and use `BrowserVC`'s implementation.

`super.super.someMethod()` apparently isn't the answer. Is this possible?

Comment: isn't this a problem with inheritance in general?

Comment: try Protocol Extensions with default implementation if needed, avoid inheritance where possible.

Comment: If you need this, then you architecture is broken. Don't look for workarounds for bad architecture.

Answer (score 0):

There's a (convoluted) way to do this but it requires that the intermediate class "contributes" to the bypassing of its override.

For example:

```
class A 
{
  func doIt(_ parameter:Int) { print("A.doIt(\(parameter))") }
}

class B:A
{

   override func doIt(_ parameter:Int) { print("B.doIt(\(parameter))") }
   var super_doIt:(Int)->() { return super.doIt }
}

class C:B
{
   override func doIt(_ parameter:Int) 
   { super.super_doIt(parameter) }   
}

let c = C()
c.doIt(3)    // A.doIt(3)
```

Comment: An easier solution is to create a different method in `A` which is `final` and that contains the implementation. `A.doIt` can call it internally. In that way all subclasses will still have access to the original implementation.
However, in a good OOP architecture all subclasses should call `super.doIt` anyway. They shouldn't just replace the implementation, potentially breaking the superclass.

Comment: @Sulthan, I totally agree but I wanted to illustrate a way to do it without modifying the original class.